# Making NgxECharts Chart Responsive?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, echarts, ngx-echarts

In this Stackblitz Demo the chart is responsive horizontally.  It expands and shrinks with the container.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qpdp1k?file=src%2Fmain.template.html

```
<div style="height: 10px; width: 300px">
  <div
    echarts
    [autoResize]="false"
    (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)"
    [options]="options"
    class="demo-chart"
  ></div>
</div>
```

How do we also make it responsive in the vertical direction?  Currently it overflows the containing `div` vertically.